# How do i transform an array of object into just one object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that I need to transform into objects with key names which is `{key}{index)`

```
const input = [
    {
        data: 'Abc',
        quantity: '1'
    },
    {
        data: 'Def',
        quantity: '2'
    },
    // ...
]
```

Below is an example of the output where the index would be appended to the key name which results in data1, quantity1, data2, quantity2..

```
const output = { data1: 'Abc', quantity1: 1, data2: 'Def', quantity2: 2 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const result = input.reduce((obj, item, index) => {
        Object.keys(item)
        .forEach(key=>{
            obj[key+(index+1)] = item[key]
        })
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Use `reduce`:

```js
const result = input.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
    let {data, quantity} = item;
    
    // (index + 1) because obviously the index is 0-based, and in
    // your example you started from 1
    acc["data" + (index + 1)] = data;
    acc["quantity" + (index + 1)] = quantity;

    return acc;
}, {});
```